# YUI menu, handling "onclick" from markup

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-menu

Would like to know if is it possible to handle onclick event via Html markup.
([link text](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/#usingonclick))

I know many YUI widgets can use yuiConfig to add configuration properties directly from markup ! (like Treeview)

Anybody knows ?

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, sorry...
Just used the html onclick event handler on the 'a class="yuimenuitemlabel"'